# Can I configure mmc snap-ins to behave in the same manner as local admin tools on Microsoft Servers?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-8.1, mmc

I'm running into a problem using the Microsoft MMC and RSAT tool snap-ins. Specifically, when I run Print Management from the RSAT tools on the local server, I am able to see all ports installed when at Print Servers>CO-Print-1>Ports. When I use the MMC and add the Print Management snap-in, I navigate to the same location and I see no ports installed. This same behavior is seen in the RSAT tools installed on my local workstation. I have a feeling this is a configuration issue on my workstation, but I haven't found anything to support that idea.

My workstation is Windows 8.1 and the server is 2012 R2.

Any help with this is much appreciated; thank you all in advance!